# Is "that" required or optional after is/are (or some other equivalent) when expressing a statement/fact?

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction

It sounds like the video is [saying](https://youtu.be/ok_r-mody8w?t=77) (link with a time stamp corresponds the following)

> All right, so this is interesting, and it's a valid question, but what it **comes down to**
>   is every kid has a different learning style.

"every kid has a different learning style" is a statement/fact, which plays a role of object of "comes down to" as whole.

In this case, is "that" required or optional to form this sentence in written English?

> what it comes down to is **that** every kid has a different learning style

Comment: This is actually similar to [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/152911/extended-indirect-structures/334802#334802). People throw whole clauses in without connecting phrases anymore.

Answer (score 0):

"*What it comes down to*" is an idiomatic expression used to highlight a main, or underlying point. It essentially means the same as "basically".

> It's a valid question, but basically, every kid has a different learning style.

I expect it shares a root meaning with the expression "[boil down to"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/boil-down-to-sth). When you *literally* boil something, it reduces down to its component parts. Used as a metaphor, it is used to show that you have deconstructed something complex to show the most basic, underlying reason or main point.

> What it boils down to is that every kid has a different learning style.

Comment: In the original citation, there is a "is" in there, so, the whole statement "every kid has a different learning style" is the object of "is", right?

Comment: @peterpanai Yes.

Comment: In that situation, is "that" unnecessary, required or optional?